# Can we use gerunds with the verb "abuse"?

Tags: gerunds

Can we use gerunds with the verb "abuse"?

If not, what's an alternative?

Here's my attempt at an alternative:

> Every time I see a spruce I begin chewing its needles, so I think I abuse chewing spruce needles.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I think you could use gerunds with the verb "abuse". I don't know if it would be technically correct, but as a native English speaker, I would understand the meaning, and wouldn't find it extremely strange. An example might look like:

> I FIND THIS ABUSING OF THE CAPS LOCK KEY MORALLY ABHORRENT

*But* the word "abuse" is also *already usable as a noun*, so it would be more natural to just say:

> I FIND THIS ABUSE OF THE CAPS LOCK KEY MORALLY ABHORRENT